# Android GCM packet sending

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

Can I send many push notifications with one request using [Android GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)?

Comment: Yes. You can. But one by one. Not in bunch. You can make a loop and send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can send the same message to up to 1000 devices.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table1

But we can't send different notifications to different devices with the one request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I send them in blocks of 1000 users using this code:

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields['data'] = $message;

$headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);
//echo "Reg ids: ".var_dump($fields['registration_ids'])."<br>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < 9998; $i++) {
        $registration_ids[$i+2] = $i;
    }
echo "Total necessary requests to GCM: ".(intval(count($registration_ids)/1000)+1)."<br>";
for ($j = 0; $j < count($registration_ids)/1000; $j++) {
    echo "Processing request number ".($j + 1)."...<br>";
    $fields['registration_ids'] = array();
    for($i=0;$i < 1000 && ($i+1000*$j) < count($registration_ids);$i++){
        $fields['registration_ids'][$i] = $registration_ids[$i+1000*$j];
    }
    echo "Sending push to devices: ".(1000*$j)." - ".(count($fields['registration_ids'])+1000*$j)."<br>";

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 //var_dump($fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //$result = true;
    if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    else
        echo "Curl success<br>";

    echo $result."<br>";
```

I hope you find this code useful

Comment: Thanks but I mean sending by one request. So according to docs and @Chintan Rathod it is possible to send only identical notifications for different devices per one request.

Comment: You can't say it as different devices. I think you have meaning of Push Notification like peer to peer notification. But GCM isn't mean that. If you fire any Push Notification from server, it will deliver it as much to devices which are registered with GCM.

Comment: Just to clarify. I have 2 different devices registered and I would like to send notification "Hello" to first device and "Hi" to the sencond. With one request. Is it possible?

Comment: @DmitryTeplyakov, Answer : **No**. you have to bifurcate your message while sending from server one by one. Like you need to set some flags in database that will take that "value" from database and based on it, send message.

Comment: Ok, I get you now, there are two possible answers: You can send the same message to up to 1000 devices with one request, but you can't send two different messages to the same device for example, this is due to the nature of the json object they are specting. It cannot contain an array of json objects inside or anything like that. **To send two different pushes you will need to curl_exec() twice.**

Comment: @cvacas Sorry, but my question was "can I send many notifications with one request". In your answer there many requests will be done. So I can't accept it